# How to choose wallet with web3

Tags: web3js, metamask, myetherwallet

I have MEW and Metamask installed.

When I am trying to send a transaction using:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction()
```

It always uses Metamask. May I know how can I specify I want to use MEW instead?

Answer (score 2):

The MEW browser extension isn't a web3 provider, so you can't use it to send transactions directly on your website, like with MetaMask.

Besides that, most web3 providers inject a global web3 object. If you have multiple browser extensions (or other software) injecting web3 providers, they will override each other.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea how can I sendTransaction with MEW?

Comment: It's not possible to send transactions through MEW directly from your website. You can instruct users to send a transaction through their preferred method, or implement some kind of wallet functionality yourself, depending on your use case.

Comment: Furthermore, it makes no sense to use MEW. MetaMask can send transactions as well. No need to make it complicated.